# _id value not saved for embedded document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

**Post** embeds many **Comments**.

`_id` is an `Integer` type field for Posts, but a `String` one - for Comments.

**post.rb:**

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :_id, type: Integer
  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String

  embeds_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

**comment.rb:**

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :_id, type: String
  field :content, type: String
  embedded_in :post
end
```

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:_id, :title, :content)
    end
end
```

**comments_controller.rb:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comments = @post.comments
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.new
    end

    def edit
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @comment.save
                format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, post: @comment }
            else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private
        def set_comment
            @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
            @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        end

        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:_id, :content)
        end
end
```

When I add comments it saves only the value for the content field for the comment but not its _id which is entered by me. Though this works for the **post model**:

```
> db.posts.findOne()
{
    "_id" : 23,
    "title" : "First Post",
    "content" : "Text of the 1st post",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "content" : "Comment for the 1st post"
        },
        {
            "content" : "2nd comment"
        },
        {
            "content" : "asdfagzcbzcv"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this app on github which is publicly available at https://github.com/tenzan/blog.git

Comment: why have you added _id field in models, when they are added by default.

Comment: I need to access the embedded document with URL: `/posts/:post_id/comments/:id/` and knowing the information about post id and comment id will give me an idea what embedded document I'm accessing. Maybe the question with post and comments is not the best...

Answer (score 0):

Let _id field clean :)

From your `post` object you got by `Post.find( params[:post_id] )`, you can do `post.comments.find( params[:comment_id] )`.

There is no optimisation do to with `post.comments[ params[:comment_id] ]` (if I correctly understand what you were trying to do).

If you realy want to show a cleaner comment id to you users, you can implement yourself a field like `custom_id` or use the gem `acts_as_list`.